# Not sure what my job title is

Tags: title

I'm not sure if my job title exists.

My duties have been defined along the way.

My employer has defined my job as  "Marketing Research", but knowing what Marketing Research is, and its job description (which is much more glamorous than mine), I don't think it is.

I was wondering if there's a job title closer to what I do.

So, I'm going to describe what I do (I work in a forensic psychologist's office). Everything I do revolves around "researching the internet":

1) Creating contact lists on Excel (leads-potential sales contact) that may include: business name, address,phone, e-mail, key people, etc. I also update these contact lists on a regular basis, as there are thousands of contacts.

2) Sometimes, I need to review databases, segment them per region, and assess what geographic areas are lacking leads...we have several offices, so the idea is to keep expanding the number of leads.

3) Sometimes I need to find out urgent information ("anything": it can go from supporting evidence of a health condition causation, a legal standard, to background check related information).

4) Prepare country condition reports. Since many of our cases have to do with immigration matters, I usually have to prepare comprehensive reports of country conditions (which of course requires researching the internet).

5) I've also been required to do research on upcoming networking events, prices from the competition, and other tasks that generally imply: researching information from the internet and putting it together to analyze it.

So, what's my job? Is there any specific name for it?

I must also admit I've occasionally foisted the term "Market Researcher" too, but I'm aware it's a far-stretched term...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For your actual job title, you need to ask your employer.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have a title....

Comment: Maybe I don't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your title should be either a "[market research analyst](https://www.bls.gov/ooh/business-and-financial/market-research-analysts.htm#tab-2)" (as defined by the U.S. Bureau of Labor and Statistics) or just plain old "researcher."